# Как загрузить картинку в аватар из галерею и на адрес сервера?

Tags: android, imageview, uri

Я использую Websocket. Вот код с помощью которого я загружаю из галерею картинку в аватарку. Но мне еще надо эту картинку которую я выбрала из галереи отправить на сервер. Как мне это сделать?

```
     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                iv_photo_my.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                iv_photo_my.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно в какой кодировке вы должны это отправлять. Поэтому я предложу вариант который используется мной, чтобы как-то определить то что вам нужно. Код будет на Kotlin, но с java в целом они практически полностью похожи и проблем с пониманием-переводом быть не должно. После выбора фотографии вы получаете ее uri:

```
val fileUri = data.data!!
```

дальше вам нужно так же как-то получить имя и размер:

```
var name = ""
var size: Long? = null
```

для этого можно использовать `contentResolver`:

```
fileUri.let { returnUri ->
                        contentResolver.query(returnUri, null, null, null, null)
                    }?.use { cursor ->
                        val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                        val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
                        cursor.moveToFirst()
                        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                        size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)
                    }
```

следующим этапом вы должны конвертировать файл в стринг. Поэтому считываем байты:

```
val content = data.data?.let { uri -> contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { it!!.readBytes() } }
```

и кодируем (кодировку я не знаю какую вы используете):

```
val fileContent = String(content!!, Charsets.ISO_8859_1)
```

ну и после того как вы получили содержимое файла в виде стринга, можно его отправлять по схеме которая у вас должна быть. Если вы не знаете в каком виде сервер ждет файл, то лучше связаться с бекендерами и узнать подробности.